# Need help building query laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get rings from the database. but only filter is the homepage is 1 or 0.

I only need the rows where homepage is 1.

[image]

This is what i tried

```
        $ringen = RingKoppelCategory::with('ringen')->get()->where('homepage', '=' , 1);
```

returns null

And when i put the ->get() at the end of the query builder it checks the ringkoppelcategory table for a homepage which is not what i want it to do.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'homepage' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `ringkoppelcategory` where `homepage` = 1
```

I need to get the rings relationship from the ringkoppelcategory, but only the rings where the homepage is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a function to pass along a `where` within your `with`.

```
$ringen = RingKoppelCategory::with(['ringen' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('homepage', '=' , 1);
}])->get();
```

More information is found in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following query

```
$ringen = RingKoppelCategory::whereHas('ringen', function ($query) {
$query->where('homepage', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

Check Querying Relationship Existence section at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)